# Characters changed during the save XML file

Tags: xml, character-encoding

I have an XML file (ISO-8859-1) containing advertisements , example :

```
    <annonce id="100">
        <image><![CDATA[<img src="images/geneve-25.jpg" border="1" style="border-color:#CCCCCC"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;]]></image>
        <entete><![CDATA[<strong>Gen&egrave;ve</strong>]]></entete>
        <ref><![CDATA[<span class="refGE">(r&eacute;f CRB100)]]></ref>
        <nouveau><![CDATA[<br/><br/>]]></nouveau>
        <description>   
            <detail><![CDATA[<strong>Grande Brasserie / Restaurant</strong><br/><br/> 
                 90 places et Terrasse privée de 80 places.<br/>
                 Matériaux de grande qualité. Emplacement No.1 en grand développement, 
                 Rive Gauche, quartier très tranquille, C.A. important.<br/><br/>
                 <span class="info_annonce_jaune">Affaire traitée sur rdv uniquement.</span><br/>]]>
            </detail>
        </description>
</annonce>
```

I'am adding a new element and save the file :

```
$racine = simplexml_load_file($fichier);
                        $annonce = $racine->addChild('annonce');
                        $annonce->addAttribute('id', $_POST['id']);
                        $annonce->addChild('ref', $_POST['ref']);
                        $annonce->addChild('image', $_POST['image']);
                        $annonce->addChild('entete', $_POST['entete']);
                        $annonce->addChild('nouveau', $_POST['nouveau']);
                        $annonce->addChild('description', $_POST['description']);
                        $fichier = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT', $fichier);
                        file_put_contents($fichier, $racine->asXML());
```

I have 2 problems :

1 The XML file header before saving with new element looked like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
```

After saiving, the encoding disapper

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

2 Secondly, many characters are changed :

```
    <annonce id="100">
        <image>&lt;img src=&quot;images/geneve-25.jpg&quot; border=&quot;1&quot; style=&quot;border-color:#CCCCCC&quot;/&gt;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;</image>
        <entete>&lt;strong&gt;Gen&amp;egrave;ve&lt;/strong&gt;</entete>
        <ref>&lt;span class=&quot;refGE&quot;&gt;(r&amp;eacute;f CRB100)</ref>
        <nouveau>&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;</nouveau>
        <description>   
            <detail>&lt;strong&gt;Grande Brasserie / Restaurant&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt; 
                 90 places et Terrasse privée de 80 places.&lt;br/&gt;
                 Matériaux de grande qualité. Emplacement No.1 en grand développement, 
                 Rive Gauche, quartier très tranquille, C.A. important.&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;
                 &lt;span class=&quot;info_annonce_jaune&quot;&gt;Affaire traitée sur rdv uniquement.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;br/&gt;
            </detail>
        </description>
</annonce>
```

All ![CDATA[ disappeared!!!
Any ideas?

PS : is there a possibility to save with an indent style? The new element is online in the file...

Comment: Well what is the encoding of the file? Try some editor like notepad++ to find out which encoding it has.

Comment: The file encoding before manipulation is : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

Comment: Maybe `iconv` makes trouble. You're converting from `UTF-8` to `ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT` I assume. What happens if you don't convert the data? What is also possible that some function escapes your data to this format, to be readable in html/php.

Comment: I'm converting back to ISO-8859-1 because the function simplexml_load_file($fichier) convert my XML file(ISO-8859-1) to UTF-8